Azure-data-factory creating a pipeline with tenure parameter
how to create an archiving pipeline which will have only 1 parameter called "tenure" which will copy the last 3 year data from "Source" folder to a different folder "Archive" and delete them from "Source" folder tenure - 3 soure:: 2020/A.csv .... Archive: 2022/A.csv, 2023/A.csv, 2024/A.csv
I tried above problem by parameterizing filename in copydata activity it is copying empty files with names 2022, 2023, 2024 how to solve this problem

Could you share the full approach? This helps in finding the issue in your approach. Share the pipeline screenshots/ Json script of pipeline

what is your requirement here? Do you want to copy the source folder 2020 data files to different folders 2022,2023,2024?

I have 5 folders in source container with folder names 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024 inside each folder there is 1 csv file. Now I need to copy last year folders which are 2022, 2023, 2024 folders to another container based on 1 parameter called tenure.

As you want to copy last 3 years source folders to target folders, you can make use of for-loop in ADF pipeline.
First create tenure parameter of int type and give a default value of current year 2024 for that in the pipeline parameters section.
Now, take a For-Each activity and give below expression in that.
@range(sub(pipeline().parameters.tenure,2),3)


This will generate an array of [2022,2023,2024] if the parameter value is 2024. The pipeline will iterate through this array and will copy from each source folder 2022 to target folder 2022 in each iteration.
Inside For-Each, take a copy activity. For the copy activity source dataset, give your target container in the dataset. For remaining target location path, use wildcard file path in the copy activity source.

For the sink of the copy activity, you need to parameterize the dataset folder path. Create a string parameter and use that in folder path of the dataset.

In the copy activity sink, give @item() as value for this parameter.

To delete the tenure-3 folder from source, after for-loop, take a delete activity. Create a dataset with source container and parameterize the folder path in the dataset. Give the below expression for that parameter in the pipeline.
@string(sub(pipeline().parameters.tenure,2))


This will give the results like below and will delete tenure-3 folder from source.


thank you it worked but we need to delete copied folders from the source after they successfully copied to target folder

If you want delete every folder, put the delete activity inside for-loop after copy activity and give the @item() as parameter value. If you want to delete only the tenure-3 folder, then the above appraoch will work.
